# dynamic options in select depends on another select pure php

Tags: php, arrays, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with a main menu sub menu and another level of submenu i was thinking if it is possible to change this into three select box wherein when i choose the main menu only the submenu available to that main menu will be shown on the sub menu select and then when selecting or the default value on submenu the submenu level two of that submenu will be shown on the last select option.. Is it possible to do this on pure php only?

Comment: you need to use ajax  with javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in pure PHP.

You have to use ajax, with jQuery for example, to update your submenu dropdown based on the first one. PHP is only processed on server side so you can't do dynamic display based on client interactions without javascript.

Comment: i thought this would be easy can you give sample for this one?something i can fiddle with?i keep on searching for sample but i cant find any